# Vanishing of cohomology of a multiple of a divisor on surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be a an effective divsior on a smooth projective surface $X$. Does there exists any result (Preferably a classification result) in the literature which deals with the vanishing of first cohomology of multiple of that divisor i.e. in symbols $h^1(\mathcal O_X(mD))=0$ for almost all positive integers $m$? Is there a specific name for this divisors?

Any remark or reference from anyone is welcome.

Comment: There may be some version of Riemann--Roch that could help. For instance, I think that $\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X(mD))$ will be a quadratic polynomial in $m$, and perhaps the coefficients can be quantised. (Don't quote me on it though. :-) )

Comment: If $D^2<0$ then it does not vanish. Riemann-Roch gives you that $\chi(mD)=\frac{1}{2}D^2m^2+$l.o.t. and this is negative for $m>\!>0$ by the assumption. So if the divisor is "rigid" it seems to not vanish for $m$ large. Maybe you can find some deformation theoretic interpretation of the cohomology group $h^1(D,mN_{D/X})$ where $N_{D/X}$ is the normal bundle and use the restriction sequence to relate this to $h^1(mD)$, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: @Mentos, could you please give me a reference?